# How to downgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu Server 10.10?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php5, ubuntu-10.10, downgrade

After moving my website to the new Ubuntu Server 10.10 it started to work with errors. I know  the problem is in the PHP compatibility. Insead of fixing the website I prefer to downgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.2 this time.

How to do that on Ubuntu Server 10.10? I have found the solution for Ubuntu 10.04 but seems it won't work anymore.

Comment: Please note that current 5.2 release is the last one supported, so fixing your code may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://thejibe.com/blog/10/10/php-5210-debs-ubuntu-1010-maverick

http://harx.nl/component/content/article/2-linux/22-installingphp52onubuntu1010

Hope the above helps

Comment: I used the quick method which I have found in user's comments on your first link http://randyfay.com/node/63

Answer (score 0):

Use [this script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566808) on Ubuntu forum. It worked for me flawlessly. But the first link above has some invalid urls and the second one is customized for apache.